# "Consider" vs. "look" when asking someone to take a fact into consideration to back up one's point

Tags: difference

Is there any difference between consider and look when asking someone to take a fact into consideration to back up one's point? For example:

> That guy is really rude. **Consider** how he treated the waiter yesterday.
>
> That guy is really rude. **Look** how he treated the waiter yesterday.

Are both sentences perfectly natural?

Comment: Consider can mean 'look into'

Comment: It would be look at…

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at least in the US. 'Consider' is very slightly more formal.